# Bash diff that stops when it finds the first difference

Tags: bash, diff

I have this script that I use for backups. The problem is that it is kind of slow. I want to know if there is a diff command that stops when finds the first difference.

```
DocumentsFiles=("Books" "Comics" "Distros" "Emulators" "Facturas" "Facultad" "Laboral" "Mods" "Music" "Paintings" "Projects" "Scripts" "Tesis" "Torrents" "Utilities")
OriginDocumentsFile="E:\Documents\\"
DestinationDocumentsFile="F:\Files\Documents\\"

## loop file to file and copy in backup
for directory in "${DocumentsFiles[@]}"
do
    RealOrigin="${OriginDocumentsFile}${directory}"
    RealDestination="${DestinationDocumentsFile}${directory}"

    echo $directory
    if [ -a "$RealDestination" ]; then
        echo ok
        if diff -r $RealOrigin $RealDestination; then
            echo "${directory} are equal!"
        else
            rm -rfv $RealDestination
            cp -ruv $RealOrigin "${DestinationDocumentsFile}"
        fi
    else 
        cp -ruv $RealOrigin "${DestinationDocumentsFile}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/questions/1039197/diff-stop-after-first-difference solve your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**`diff -q`** reports "only when files differ" (per [`man diff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)), so I believe it'll stop after the first difference.

But this is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). Really you need a better backup program like **`rsync`**:

> It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination.

*From [`man rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)*

Comment: Check `borgbackup`

Comment: Thanks men, I was using windows and that was the reason for my to not use rsync. But now I realice that I can use Linux Subsystem and get the same result.

Comment: My experiments seem to prove that `diff -q` doesn't "stop after the first difference", and there's nothing I can see in the docs to suggest that it should.

Comment: @mike What experiments did you try? There are plenty of factors that could make it seem like it doesn't, though I don't know for sure that it doesn't.